# What is the name of this red chili with white scars?

Tags: identification, chili

I am looking for the name of the following chilies:

[image]

---

They are all off the same kind. The red one on the right is ripe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are jalapeno chilies. They get redder and develop these white striations (stretch marks) as they age.  You'll find the chili on the left to be less hot and progressively getting hotter to the hottest on the right.

Comment: thank you for your answer @stormy ! Can you tell which kind of jalapeno they are? I allread have jalapenos and they look different to these (They are not that thick).

Comment: Then you didn't have jalapenos.  I've got the same peppers to include; serrano, habanero, thai and cayenne.  There is only one jalapeno which is actually a cultivar of Capsicum annuum.  They are fattish, the size of your little finger and are quite unique.  No mistake, well, never say never but these are just jalapenos.  Pickling them is my favorite way to preserve them and this year I am slicing them up to dehydrate.  Have you ever done Thai food?  The chile pepper made it around the world as the second favorite spice next to salt.  These are completely typical of jalapeno...

Comment: I googled a bit and you are absolutely right. Thank you for your help and bringing me on the right track.

Comment: Thank you!  Any time you need answers to anything in your landscape just holler!!